# Entity Framework reflection invoke where method of a table, mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection, where-clause, invoke

Trying to do a reflection call to table and invoke the where method.
Use in MVC (2),

Data in entity framework. Could hardcode for the currently two tables that im trying to get data out off.

Trouble at how to invoke the where method.

And simply surprised that I did not find answer to this already? So if already answered, and iv not searched the right thing, im sure you'll let me know.

have the following

```
string search_table

PropertyInfo prop = database.GetType().GetProperty(search_table);
object table = prop.GetValue(WRG,null);
var methods = table.GetType().GetMethods();

var where_method = table.GetType().GetMethod("Where");
var result_data = where_method.Invoke(table, new object[]{"table", "table.-FIELD-NAME.Contains(search_string)"});
```

If not using reflection, then I would call the where method with
    var result_data = database.-TABEL-.Where(t => t.-FIELD.Contains(search_string));

So have tried copping that info into the invoke, nothing.

where invoke asks for: (object obj, object[] parameters)

thank you anyone pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Where` is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx), usually defined in the [`System.Linq.Queryable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.aspx) or [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) classes, depending on whether or not the object implements [`IQueryable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx).

The `Enumerable` version expects a `Func<T, bool>` parameter. The `Queryable` version expects an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` parameter. Neither version accepts a string representation of the parameter. If you need to pass the parameter as a string, you'll need to look at the [LINQ Dynamic Query library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

Comment: Right, I understand this now. Basically can not use Where reflectively as it will not point to the correct Where method declaration made by entity framework, only to the abstract method declaration.